# Inputting 2 Hex Numbers and a string in one line of code

Tags: c++, c, input, hex, output

I want to enter a line of code that will look something like the following:

```
cin >> hex >> n1 >> s >> hex >> n2;
```

The program needs to be able to prompt the user to input a hex number followed by an expression followed by another hex number. I then follow with a series of string compares to 
compare with the expression and either `ad`, `sub`, and etc to the two hex numbers.

I can do this with the c code like

```
scanf("%x %s %x", &n1, s, &n2);
```

How can the above statement of scanf be implemented similarly in c++?

Comment: BTW: `scanf("%x %s %x" ...` and `scanf("%x%s%x" ...` function the same as both %s and %x themselves consume input spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stream manipulators http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/
for example:

```
std::cin >> std::hex >> n1 >> s >> n2;
```

Comment: Will this make two hex numbers separated by a string or 3 hex numbers?

Comment: It changes the mode for reading numbers. Any number you retrieve will be a hex value until you pass std::dec or std::oct.